Unable to Set Value of DataCardValue Control in PowerApps Test Studio
Unable to Set Value of DataCardValue Control in PowerApps Test Studio
Steps to Reproduce:

Create a PowerApps application with a form that includes a DataCardValue control (e.g., DataCardValue5).
Attempt to set the value of this control using the SetProperty function in Test Studio as shown above.
Observe the error message that appears.

I am encountering an issue while trying to set the value of a DataCardValue control in PowerApps Test Studio. Specifically, I am attempting to set the value using the following code:
SetProperty(DataCardValue5.Value, {'Value': "trial desc"});
However, I receive the error message:
The property 'DataCardValue5.Value' cannot be used in PowerApps Test Studio.
Expected Result:
I expect to be able to set the value of the DataCardValue control in Test Studio without encountering an error.
Why is this and how can I solve it?
I am encountering an issue while trying to set the value of a DataCardValue control in PowerApps Test Studio. Specifically, I am attempting to set the value using the following code:
SetProperty(DataCardValue5.Value, {'Value': "trial desc"});
However, I receive the error message:
The property 'DataCardValue5.Value' cannot be used in PowerApps Test Studio.
Expected Result:
I expect to be able to set the value of the DataCardValue control in Test Studio without encountering an error.
FYI:
IT works for SetProperty('DataCardValue29'.SelectedItems, Table({'Value':{'Id':585690002,'Value':"Dropped"}}))
But not for SetProperty(DataCardValue5.Value, {'Value': "trial desc"});
I also tried SetProperty(DataCardValue5.Value, "trial desc");

What type of control is DataCardValue5?
